Why does chrome cut some of my query string values upon paste? Is it related to a specific recent release?
Within recent months, pasting some of my domain urls into the location bar, e.g. mydomain.com?foo=bar&foo1=bar1 it removes the query string values, loading mydomain.com?.  If I repaste it again it works fine, only the first paste removes them.  I'm trying to find the chrome release that created this behavior.
